# Express.js throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I try to make a API with express and mysql.
My problem is that when I send a request to my node server ( with Insomnia ) but every time I get an error...

> node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'typeCast' in null

```
var express = require('express'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "psword",
    database: "bd"
  });
  

var app = express(); 

var express = require('express'); 

var hostname = 'localhost'; 
var port = 3000; 
 
var app = express(); 

var myRouter = express.Router(); 
 

myRouter.route('/:montant/:sec/:loc/:statut/:type/:anc/:caff')

.get(function(req,res){ 
    var sql= "select * from plateforme";
    con.getConnection(function(sql) {
        con.query(sql, function (result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Errore login: " + err);
        }
        else {
          console.log("Result: " + result);
          if(result.length > 0){
            console.log(result[0].IdUtente);
            IdUtente = result[0].IdUtente;
       }
      }
        });
      });
      res.json({montant : req.params.montant ,secteur : req.params.sec, localisation:  req.params.loc ,statut: req.params.statut, 
        type: req.params.type, anciente: req.params.anc ,chiffreAffaire: req.params.caff, methode : req.method});
        
})
```

I didn't know if this error come from my code or lib.
And I try all the stackoverflow's topic but no one solved my problem.

Update :

```
con.getConnection(function(err, connection)  {
        var sql= "select * from plateforme";
        connection.query(sql, function (result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          //console.log("Result: " + result);
          if(result.length > 0){
              console.log(result[0].IdUtente);
              IdUtente = result[0].IdUtente;
       }
      }
        );
      });
con.releaseConnection();
```

New error :

> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
> ^

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: it should be `con.getConnection(function(err, connection) {` your passing the wrong thing to `con.query(sql,` which should actully be `connection.query(sql,` you should recheck the docs

Comment: also if you're using a pool, you should release the connection, else will run out of connections

Comment: I change my code like you tell me but now I get throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: can you make edit with updated code?

Comment: you cant do `if (err) throw err;` instead just `console.error(err)` it. Then fix the error

Comment: also not sure what `con.releaseConnection` is, it should also be inside after query and be `connection.release()` Is all in the docs with good examples: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

Comment: Thanks a lot it work, I've use .query() instead of getConnection ect